# How can switch to another account to share in Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to switch to another account to share a content on my time feed with Facebook SDK. For example, I have 1 personal account and another fan page is set up in the same personal account, when user's using my app, I have a function to share a content on FB, but I want to select my fan page account, not my personal account. Anyone has any ideas about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this case. I called Facebook Graph API to get the list of pages which current user is owning, I'm using this service:

`[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/accounts" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"id, name, category"}]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  //do your stuffs here to get the pages list
}]`

Then, when sharing the post to particular page, I take its page_id and send request via Graph API: `NSString *pageId = [defaultDict objectForKey:@"id"];

        //send photo to page
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",pageId] parameters:@{@"source" : self.image, @"message" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.descriptionToSend, websiteUrl]} HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       //do your stuff here to notify user either uploading successfully or not.
}];`